# Остается последняя запись в БД django

Tags: python, django

Мне нужно чтобы водители привязывались к юзеру(У юзера может быть много водителей).  В таком виде у меня записывается только одна запись на юзера. Как мне можно сделать много записей на юзера?

```
class Policyholder(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Имя", max_length = 64)
    familyname = models.CharField("Фамилия", max_length = 64)
    father_name = models.CharField("Отчество", max_length = 64)
    driver_age = models.IntegerField("Возвраст")
    experience = models.IntegerField("Стаж")
    admin = models.OneToOneField(User , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кажется проблема в последней строке OneToOneField.
Используйте ForeignKey.

P.S. для поля 1-1 создается также ограничение unique. Чтобы его снять, нужно сделать миграцию

Comment: UNIQUE constraint failed: new__calculator_policyholder.id

Comment: А миграцию сделали?

Comment: Не дает сделать миграцию, выдает данную ошибку

Comment: Создал новую БД- заработало